# Progress bar not updating even with SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this inside `index.html`

```
<body>

<script>
window.onload=function() {
  let videoDiv = createVideoDiv()
  document.getElementById("contentVideo").appendChild(videoDiv);

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(inEvent){
    controlVideo(inEvent.keyCode);
  });


}
</script>


<div id="progressBarWrapper">
  <div id="progressBar"></div>
</div>

<div id="contentVideo"></div> 

</body>
```

and this `css`

```
#progressBarWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height:15px;
  background-color: black;
}

#progressBar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

this is how the video div is created:

```
function createVideoDiv() {  
  var video = document.createElement("VIDEO");
  video.setAttribute('controls', '');
  //video.setAttribute('autoplay', '');
  video.setAttribute('preload', 'auto');
  video.setAttribute('width', larguraVideo);
  video.setAttribute('id', 'video');

  var source = document.createElement("SOURCE");
  source.setAttribute('src', obterVideoClicado());
  source.setAttribute('type', 'video/mp4');

  video.addEventListener('progress', function() {
    var range = 0;
    var bf = this.buffered;
    var time = this.currentTime;

    while(!(bf.start(range) <= time && time <= bf.end(range))) {
        range += 1;
    }
    var loadStartPercentage = bf.start(range) / this.duration;
    var loadEndPercentage = bf.end(range) / this.duration;
    var loadPercentage = loadEndPercentage - loadStartPercentage;
    setTimeout(ajustarProgressBar, 40, loadPercentage * 100);

  });

  video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
    var myBar = document.getElementById("progressBarWrapper");
    myBar.style = "display:none;";
    video.play();
  });

  video.appendChild(source);

  return video;
}
```

this is how the progress bar is adjusted

```
function ajustarProgressBar(valor) {
  var progressBar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
  progressBar.style.width = valor + "%";
}
```

Even the progress bar is being fired by

```
setTimeout(ajustarProgressBar, 40, loadPercentage * 100);
```

the progress bar is not updating and stays 0% all the time.

The progress bar is to be adjusted by the video download progress.

The video progress is working fine. I have printed that to console and the values are changing as the video download progresses.

Comment: maybe you meant to call the function in `setTimeout` with `ajustarProgressBar(40)` rather than `ajustarProgressBar, 40` ?

Comment: no I want to call ajustarProgresBar(loadPercentage * 100) with a 40 or more timeout.

Comment: then use `setTimeout(() => ajustarProgresBar(loadPercentage * 100), 40)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass param to function:

```js
var valor = loadPercentage * 100;
var delay = 100;
setTimeout(() => ajustarProgressBar(valor), delay);
```

--Edit
Your video progress event listener would now look like:

```
 video.addEventListener('progress', function() {
    var range = 0;
    var bf = this.buffered;
    var time = this.currentTime;

    while(!(bf.start(range) <= time && time <= bf.end(range))) {
        range += 1;
    }
    var loadStartPercentage = bf.start(range) / this.duration;
    var loadEndPercentage = bf.end(range) / this.duration;
    var loadPercentage = loadEndPercentage - loadStartPercentage;
    var valor = loadPercentage * 100;
    var delay = 100;
    setTimeout(() => ajustarProgressBar(valor), delay);

  });
```

Comment: I don't get it. Where do I put this? I mean, how do I specify the delay?

Comment: Updated the answer. I assumed `loadPercentage * 100` is value that is being changed over time. Also added minor delay of 100ms.

Comment: yes, the value is updating but the progress bar continues without updating.

Comment: Hmm when you inspect #progressBar element in dev tools do you see style.width property updated?

Comment: HOLY CRAP, I do not believe this crap. I have restarted the machine and it is now working. OK my code had a problem your answer fixed but it is now working after the restart. THANKS!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The `setTimeout` function takes 2 parameters:

1. The function to call after the delay time
2. The delay time in milliseconds

So to call your function you must make a function that will call your function like this:

```
setTimeout(() => ajustarProgresBar(loadPercentage * 100), 40);
```

So in your code it might look like this:

```
    var loadStartPercentage = bf.start(range) / this.duration;
    var loadEndPercentage = bf.end(range) / this.duration;
    var loadPercentage = loadEndPercentage - loadStartPercentage;
    setTimeout(() => ajustarProgressBar(loadPercentage*100), 40);
```

Comment: ok, thanks. Changed that but the progress bar continues there, at zero. No updates whatsoever. LoadPercentage is changing fine.

Comment: what causes the `progress` event to fire? are you sure it's happening?

Comment: progress happens as the video downloads. Yes, it is happening. I have output that value to console and I see the progress... 0, 0,1, 0.3.... 1. Now I have tried to add `progressBar.style.width = "30%";` to the last line of `ajustarProgressBar()` just to see if the bar increases to 30%. Nope, bar still at zero. Very strange.